# The Electron app.isReady() function always false?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an electron app, it goes through a couple of files before creating the first window. But when it gets to the file that should create the window I checked and it is simply never ready. I am getting the error for creating a window before the app is ready but it's not a matter of time it really is just never ready.

I even put a while loop to while the app isn't ready and it never ends, I then moved it to the very first line of the first file (after requiring the app module) and it still got stuck and I have no idea why.

*There really isn't any code to see here, it just the first line of the program there is nothing in the code that can affect it*

Comment: @please provide a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're checking the app readiness inside the loop isn't required at all. You can use the `ready` event as given in [official docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-ready) or you can use the `whenReady` method which returns a promise to check the app is ready.

```js
...
app.on('ready', () => {
    ...
    ...
});

//or

app.whenReady().then(() => {
 ...
});
```

Here is the [example](https://www.codota.com/code/javascript/functions/electron/App/whenReady) of using the `whenReady`.